# Is there a way to add a parameter during run-time?

Tags: spinnaker

At the Manual Judgement stage we were hoping we could enter a value, continue and pass that value onto Jenkins with "${#judgment("Manual Judgment")}". We can pass the predefined option but can't enter a new one. Is there a way of getting this to work or an alternative method?

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is by using pipeline parameters.

1. In configuration stage of the pipeline, add a parameter (say Name="jenkins") and configure the parameter's options (like default value, required or not)
2. Before the manual judgment step, create a Evaluate Variables stage. In the stage configuration, create a variable named "jenkins" with the value ${parameters.jenkins}
3. In manual judgment's options, add the variable ${jenkins}

Now, during the manual judgment stage, it would show an option with the value provided to the pipeline.

You could also join Spinnaker's slack here: https://join.spinnaker.io/